# Invalid Json web token in Go

Tags: json, parsing, curl, go, json-web-token

I am trying to make a Json web token authentication system with Go however I cant seem to get the parsing of the web token working.
The error occurs in the following function.

```
func RequireTokenAuthentication(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request, next http.HandlerFunc) {
authBackend := InitJWTAuthenticationBackend()

jwtString := req.Header.Get("Authorization")


token, err := jwt.Parse(jwtString, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
    if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodRSA); !ok {
        log.Println("Unexpected signing method")
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
    } else {
        log.Println("The token has been successfully returned")
        return authBackend.PublicKey, nil
    }
})

log.Println(token)
log.Println(token.Valid)

if err == nil && token.Valid && !authBackend.IsInBlacklist(req.Header.Get("Authorization")) {
    next(rw, req)
} else {
    rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
    log.P

rintln("Status unauthorized RequireTokenAuthentication")
    }
}
```

returns the following log

```
[negroni] Started GET /test/hello
2016/09/13 01:34:46 &{Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NzM5NzQ4OTAsImlhdCI6MTQ3MzcxNTY5MCwic3ViIjoiIn0.mnwEwdR8nuvdLo_4Ie43me7iph2LeSj1uikokgD6VJB7isjFPShN8E7eQr4GKwuIiLTi34_i6iJRpmx9qrPugkzvsoxX44qlFi6M7FDhVySRiYbBQwTCvKCpvhnsK8BHJyEgy813aaxOMK6sKZJoaKs5JYUvnNZdNqmENYj1BM6FdbGP-oLHuR_CJK0Pym1NMhv9zLI1rpJOGu4mfj1t4tHYZAEGirPnzYMamtrK6TyEFE6Xi4voEEadq7hXvWREg6wNSQsYgww8uOaIWLy1yLbhTkPmT8zfRwLLYLqS_UuZ0xIaSWO1mF2plvOzz1WlF3ZEHLS31T1egB1XL4WTNQe <nil> map[] <nil>  false}
2016/09/13 01:34:46 false
2016/09/13 01:34:46 Status unauthorized RequireTokenAuthentication
[negroni] Completed 401 Unauthorized in 71.628ms
```

and here is the cURL that I am using to initiate it

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NzM5NzQ4OTAsImlhdCI6MTQ3MzcxNTY5MCwic3ViIjoiIn0.mnwEwdR8nuvdLo_4Ie43me7iph2LeSj1uikokgD6VJB7isjFPShN8E7eQr4GKwuIiLTi34_i6iJRpmx9qrPugkzvsoxX44qlFi6M7FDhVySRiYbBQwTCvKCpvhnsK8BHJyEgy813aaxOMK6sKZJoaKs5JYUvnNZdNqmENYj1BM6FdbGP-oLHuR_CJK0Pym1NMhv9zLI1rpJOGu4mfj1t4tHYZAEGirPnzYMamtrK6TyEFE6Xi4voEEadq7hXvWREg6wNSQsYgww8uOaIWLy1yLbhTkPmT8zfRwLLYLqS_UuZ0xIaSWO1mF2plvOzz1WlF3ZEHLS31T1egB1XL4WTNQe" http://localhost:5000/test/hello
```

I have also tried curl without `Bearer`

```
curl -H "Authorization:eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NzM5NzQ4OTAsImlhdCI6MTQ3MzcxNTY5MCwic3ViIjoiIn0.mnwEwdR8nuvdLo_4Ie43me7iph2LeSj1uikokgD6VJB7isjFPShN8E7eQr4GKwuIiLTi34_i6iJRpmx9qrPugkzvsoxX44qlFi6M7FDhVySRiYbBQwTCvKCpvhnsK8BHJyEgy813aaxOMK6sKZJoaKs5JYUvnNZdNqmENYj1BM6FdbGP-oLHuR_CJK0Pym1NMhv9zLI1rpJOGu4mfj1t4tHYZAEGirPnzYMamtrK6TyEFE6Xi4voEEadq7hXvWREg6wNSQsYgww8uOaIWLy1yLbhTkPmT8zfRwLLYLqS_UuZ0xIaSWO1mF2plvOzz1WlF3ZEHLS31T1egB1XL4WTNQe" http://localhost:5000/test/hello
```

The error is occurring because the token is invalid `token.Valid = false` I have generated it using the following process.

Here is the router

```
router.HandleFunc("/token-auth", controllers.Login).Methods("POST")
```

Here is the login controller

```
    func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    requestUser := new(models.User)
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    decoder.Decode(&requestUser)    
    responseStatus, token := utils.Login(requestUser) //here the util file seen below is used
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(responseStatus)
    w.Write(token)

}
```

This is the util file

```
    func Login(requestUser *models.User) (int, []byte) {
        authBackend := authentication.InitJWTAuthenticationBackend()

        if authBackend.Authenticate(requestUser) {
            token, err := authBackend.GenerateToken(requestUser.UUID)
            if err != nil {
                return http.StatusInternalServerError, []byte("")
            } else {
                response, _ := json.Marshal(parameters.TokenAuthentication{token})
                return http.StatusOK, response
            }
        }
        return http.StatusUnauthorized, []byte("")
    }
```

and here is the method used to generate the token

```
    func (backend *JWTAuthenticationBackend) GenerateToken(userUUID string) (string, error) {
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodRS512)

    claims := token.Claims.(jwt.MapClaims)

    claims["exp"] = time.Now().Add(time.Hour * time.Duration(settings.Get().JWTExpirationDelta)).Unix()
    claims["iat"] = time.Now().Unix()
    claims["sub"] = userUUID

    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(backend.privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
        return "", err
    }

    return tokenString, nil
}
```

How do I fix the Token Parsing system so that the token is valid?
If you need any additional information I would be more than happy to make an edit with the respective information.
Thank

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error returned by `jwt.Parse()` says

> tokenstring should not contain 'bearer '

So if you remove "Bearer ":

```
jwtString = strings.Split(jwtString, "Bearer ")[1]
```

you get a bit further

> The token has been successfully returned

however now there's a new error:

> key is of invalid type

Sorry it's not a complete answer!

Comment: Is there any more information that I could give to you that would point to the origin of this error?

Comment: Can you describe how you're creating the key?

Comment: I have added the process I used to generate the token, Thanks!

Comment: you know what, maybe it does work if you just remove bearer. I can't tell because I don't have the public key from the example

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had already tried that, It gives me exactly the same error?

Answer (score 0):

> key is of invalid type

*type* in this context is referring to the dynamic data-type in Go.

For `SigningMethodRSA`, the public key must be of type `*rsa.PublicKey` which can be constructed by calling `jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM()`.

The key value returned to the parser might be created with something like:

```
keyStruct, _ := jwt.ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM(myPublicKeyString)
```

See:

- https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#signing-methods-and-key-types
- https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#SigningMethodRSA
- https://godoc.org/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go#ParseRSAPublicKeyFromPEM

Related:

- [How to generate JWT token always through invalid key type error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51471802/86967)